# VPN соединение открывает google.com на русском

Tags: безопасность, vpn

Почему сайт www.google.com открывается мне на русском языке, если я подключен к VPN, где ip адрес Румыния, Бухарест. К примеру сайт www.bet365.com открывается на Румынском, к тому же все куки предварительно были удалены? Если войти через браузер Tor то www.google.com откроется не на русском.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо, ваш браузер использует русский язык. Он может передавать в заголовках серверам эту информацию.
Для этого используется header `Accept-Language`
Посмотрите, например, здесь тоже должны определять язык браузера, несмотря на ip: http://www.404.ru/tools/browser/

Comment: @СашаЧерных, у меня работает

Comment: @dzhioev, снял галочку в Ad Muncher с [соответствующей настройки](https://i.gyazo.com/60cda44ebc846d98225303d81725c9ed.png) — заработало. Прошу прощения, что отвлёк сообщество.

Comment: @СашаЧерных На всякий случай, поместил в ответ другую ссылку, выдающую более подробную информацию из header'ов.